# "A Town Called Mercy" - who created the ring, and who were the narrator and the little girl?

Tags: doctor-who

In "A Town Called Mercy", who created the ring around the town, and were the

> woman narrator and little girl

anyone that has been seen before in either new or classic Who?

Comment: This really needs a better name.

Comment: @Pureferret agreed, but i couldn't (and still can't) think of a spoiler free one

Comment: I don't think those spoilers are as spoilery as you think

Comment: Indeed. The fact that there's a ring around the town isn't a spoiler - in fact, it's one of the first things we see in the episode - and similarly the fact that there's a narrator and a little girl in the story isn't a spoiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order:

> - The border around the town was created by the gunslinger using the alien Kahler technology. He places it there to let the townspeople know how far they can walk before they will be "turned back" with the threat of violence.

- Its very alien appearance is implied by the fact it draws the Doctor's attention. He scans it with the Sonic Screwdriver and pretends nothing's wrong.
- But remember rule #1: The Doctor Lies. After seeing the line and the anachronistic lights (even though we never get an actual date), he knows there is more going on here than meets the eye.

> - The identity of the narrator is unknown but it is implied that the young woman was the person who relayed the tale to her.

Comment: We do get a date -- it's five years after the US Civil War, so it's 1870, give or take a year. Which fits well with the first carbon filament lamps in 1879.

Answer (score 17):

First, the easy one: the narrator was just a narrator -- someone who lived in the town, and not related to anyone else in Who canon. I don't think she even gets a name (the only female in the credits was Sadie and I think that's the bartender.)

To the other question:

It isn't explicitly revealed who made

> the border,

but it's pretty obvious that

> the gunslinger did it. Isaac's description is basically "we woke up one day and it was there, and so was the gunslinger."

As far as why, again we can only speculate. We see very early in the episode that the gunslinger won't cross it nor fire across it. It was most likely

> a self-imposed border that provided a clear marker for where the town started and stopped. The gunslinger wouldn't enter the town because he knew that innocent people would get in the way, but sending Jex across the boundary would effectively kick him out of town, and make him "fair game."

Answer (score 14):

The narrator said at the end that the little girl was her great-great-grandmother.